# Show component based on value - Angular 2

Tags: angular, components, show-hide

I have different tabs that show ribbons with components. What I need to do is to get these components to hide when project is not loaded(undefined), and show when any of projects from dropdown list is loaded. For that, I need to grab value from project id or name, and then, rest of ribbon components can be shown.

As you can see, this is one of tabs with components:

```
<div class="tab tab-style">

<ribbon-item style="width:10%;" [title]="'Load/Save Project'">
    <project></project>
</ribbon-item>
<div class="ribbon-divider"></div>

<ribbon-item style="width:12%;" [title]="'Project settings'">
    <project-settings></project-settings>
</ribbon-item>
<div class="ribbon-divider"></div>

<ribbon-item style="width:23%;" [title]="'Environment'">
    <environment></environment>
</ribbon-item>
<div class="ribbon-divider"></div>

<ribbon-item class="pd-width" [title]="'Project dates'">
    <project-dates></project-dates>
</ribbon-item>
<div class="ribbon-divider"></div>
```

And this is project component from this tab that have project.id :

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
<select #projectSelect class="custom-select custom-select-project" (change)="loadProject(projectSelect.value)">
    <option selected disabled>Open projects</option>
    <option *ngFor="let project of projects" [value]=project.id>{{project.name}}</option>
</select>

<button class="btn-main" (click)="createNewProject()">New project</button>
<button class="btn-main">Save project</button> 
<button class="btn-main">Save as</button>
```

Basic question is, how can I set rest of my components (except project.component) to show, based on id value or data form that component? Can I use ngIf or something like that? Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent some time putting together a very basic plunk for the idea of Inputs and Outputs (the two-way data-binding that Angular employs), with nested components, as well as "transclusion" (where you're including a component within the content area of another component).

That plunk is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/lh1gkC?p=preview).

The highlights are exactly as pezetter described: in the child component that's emitting a value, you'll want to use `EventEmitter` and `Output`:

```
// SelectorComponent
@Output() valueSelected: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
selectValue(val: number) {
    this.valueSelected.emit(val);
}
```

Which will be called on the `(change)` event of your `<select>` component.

```
// SelectorComponent    
<select #selectorElem (change)="selectValue(selectorElem.value)">
```

The parent then watches for that emitted event

```
// ParentComponent (template)
<selector design="purple" (valueSelected)="valueChanges($event)"></selector>

// ParentComponent
selectedVal: string;    
valueChanges(val: number) {
    this.selectedVal = val;
}
```

Finally, you just need your components which will be hiding or showing to do so based on the value that has been outputted (passed up to the parent). In the plunk, there are 2 different ways this is done: an *ngIf on the component itself (`alt-child`):

```
// ParentComponent    
<alt-child design="gray" *ngIf="selectedVal">
```

or an *ngIf within the component (`child`)

```
// ParentComponent
<child design="red" [value]="selectedVal" [position]="2">

// ChildComponent
<div [ngClass]="design" *ngIf="value >= position">
```

This is all certainly more in-depth than it needs to be for understanding, but hopefully some can find playing around with that plunk useful.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for :) This will solve my problem for sure

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: You wouldn't mind helping me with this in private chat? I have some specific related code that i need to implement this, yet I don't quite manage to make it work. I could send you files and explain. I believe that will be simple for you :D

Comment: @VladimirTomasevicMyNameIsVLT sure, feel free to message me. If it's possible to show on a plunk, it will be much easier to debug, but I can try my best either way

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with plunker to set all files to work, so i could send you files, you will see, quite simple. Just let me know how can i send them to you :) @Jack Koppa

Answer (score 1):

Add an @Output to the project component. Then, emit an event that contains your project value that will enable the other components with an ngIf or something similar.

In your project.component.ts:

```
@Output() setProjectValue = new EventEmitter();

loadProject(val){
    let foundProject;
    //Load project logic here...
    foundProject == ...; // once its done:
    this.setProjectValue.emit(foundProject); //This will output to your parent component.
}
```

In your app.component.html (or whatever the parent is to project component):

```
<project (setProjectValue)="project = $event;"></project> //I think you're allowed to bind like this.
```

However, I would recommend just using a service/provider to store a loaded project. Set that value every time a project is loaded and use a condition in that parent component that checks if the service has a loaded project value.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using routing instead of nested components for your tabbed user interface.

The HTML would then look something like this:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="wizard">
        <a [routerLink]="['info']" routerLinkActive="active">
            Basic Information  <span [ngClass]="{'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign':
                                                  !isValid('info')}"></span>
        </a>
        <a [routerLink]="['tags']" routerLinkActive="active">
            Search Tags  <span  [ngClass]="{'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign':
                                                  !isValid('tags')}"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

There are basically the tabs and a router outlet.

Then you can easily pass data to the different routes using route parameters.

I have a complete example of this here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing in the APM-Final folder.